# Writing a trigger for a database insert using a webscraper in mysql.... keep getting different errors

Tags: mysql, insert, database-trigger

I'm not super experienced, though I do have SOME experience with MySQL. I have a problem I'm trying to solve with a trigger but it's proving much more complex than I thought and would appreciate some advice.

I have two tables. TableA and TableB.

We have customer requests coming in with their data. Each new batch of requests is scraped by a web scraper (this is the only way we can do this, so ignore how odd the process sounds), dumped into A, and then it's supposed to go to B, get rid of duplicates, then send them an email based on the data. I can't see how the web scraper is inserting the data so that's out.

Because customers submit multiple requests or the same person has different requests, the data needs to be unique, but not that unique. We want to record each request as a unique request, even if it's from the same customer. Some customers share a name, or they come back with a different request.

Therefore I made table B have the unique primary keys: name, email, address, and notes. (If I'm right about unique index, any matching index will update which would be bad if there were two John Smiths, So primary key it is).

I've tried different ways of doing this, following examples on multiple threads throughout this website, but I've been on this issue for days and I'm losing it!!!! I know I'm doing something wrong, but what?! What I ended up doing is this:

TRIGGER ON TABLEA, AFTER_INSERT:

```
tableA_to_email 
    (
    customer_name, customer_email, customer_phone, customer_address)
    VALUES ((
    SELECT 
        new.customer_name
    FROM 
       tableA
    WHERE 
        customer_name = new.customer_name), 
    (
    SELECT 
        new.customer_email
    FROM 
        tableA
    WHERE 
        customer_email = new.customer_email),         
    (
    SELECT 
        new.customer_phone
    FROM 
        tableA
    WHERE 
        customer_phone = new.customer_phone), 
    (
    SELECT 
        new.customer_address
    FROM 
        tableA
    WHERE 
        customer_address = new.customer_address))
    
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    customer_phone = VALUES(customer_phone)
```

Input into an empty table: insert INTO tableA (`customer_name`, `customer_phone`, `customer_email`, `customer_address`) VALUES("7", "0", "8", "0");

Output: MySQL said: Documentation

## 1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

I understand the error, but the input above isn't more than one row? I tried it on an empty table so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically in  your approach you can only enter 1 Result from all the selects you do, and apparently you got one that has more than one member

SO

```
INSERT INTO tableA_to_email 
    (
    customer_name, customer_email, customer_phone, customer_address)
    VALUES ((
    SELECT 
        new.customer_name
    FROM 
       tableA
    WHERE 
        customer_name = new.customer_name LIMIT 1), 
    (
    SELECT 
        new.customer_email
    FROM 
        tableA
    WHERE 
        customer_email = new.customer_email LIMIT 1),         
    (
    SELECT 
        new.customer_phone
    FROM 
        tableA
    WHERE 
        customer_phone = new.customer_phone LIMIT 1), 
    (
    SELECT 
        new.customer_address
    FROM 
        tableA
    WHERE 
        customer_address = new.customer_address LIMIT 1))

    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    customer_phone = VALUES(customer_phone)
```

Will run without problems because every select **returns only 1 row**.

But you can do only

```
INSERT INTO tableA_to_email 
( customer_name, customer_email, customer_phone, customer_address)
VALUES (
    new.customer_name, 
    new.customer_email,         
    new.customer_phone, 
    new.customer_address
)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
customer_phone = VALUES(customer_phone)
```

That works as well

Comment: I think it worked!!!!! Thank you! Going to do a more real test with a bunch of data and I will accept the answer after!